# Change colname in R over multiple datasets

Tags: r, loops, dataset

I am working with ~10 datasets and need to change the column names to match on all of them, each dataset contains the same number of columns. Currently this is what I am doing, but I know there has to be a more concise way to type it up.

week1 through week10 are the datasets I am working with.

```
colnames(week1) <- c("Itemsinfolder", "Foldersize (KB)", "Foldersubfoldersize (KB)", "User", "Level1folder", "Level2folder", "Level3folder", "Level4folder", "Level5folder")

colnames(week2) <- c("Itemsinfolder", "Foldersize (KB)", "Foldersubfoldersize (KB)", "User", "Level1folder", "Level2folder", "Level3folder", "Level4folder", "Level5folder")

colnames(week3) <- c("Itemsinfolder", "Foldersize (KB)", "Foldersubfoldersize (KB)", "User", "Level1folder", "Level2folder", "Level3folder", "Level4folder", "Level5folder")

colnames(week4) <- c("Itemsinfolder", "Foldersize (KB)", "Foldersubfoldersize (KB)", "User", "Level1folder", "Level2folder", "Level3folder", "Level4folder", "Level5folder")
```

etc. through week 10

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this at once by keeping the datasets in a `list` and change the column names using the `vector` of preferred names ('vec').  If we need to change the objects in the global environment, use `list2env` (though, it is better to keep it in the `list`)

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0("week", 1:10)), setNames, vec)
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Another option is `assign` in a `for`loop

```
wks <- paste0("week", 1:10)
for(wk in wks) assign(wk, `names<-`(get(wk), vec))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
week1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
set.seed(24)
week2 <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(5), col2 = rnorm(5))
wks <- paste0('week', 1:2)
vec <- paste0("V", 1:2)
for(wk in wks) assign(wk, `names<-`(get(wk), vec))
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("Itemsinfolder", "Foldersize (KB)", "Foldersubfoldersize (KB)", "User", 
  "Level1folder", "Level2folder", "Level3folder", "Level4folder", "Level5folder")
```